# Can't reset PS3 Super Slim (won't beep more than once)

Tags: ps3

It's been a few months since I played for the the last time. Yesterday I decided to play and realized video stopped working (don't know why, haven't changed cables or anything).

Then I tried changing ports and HDMI cables, but with no success. I read some tutorials to hard reset the console, but every time I try, I can't succeed because it won't beep more than once.

This is what should happen:

This is what's happening:

In other words, when I hold down power button while turning the console on it makes a first beep (okay), and after 5 seconds I should listen to a second beep and then to a third after a few more seconds. I can only hear the first beep. It won't work even if I hold the button longer. That means I can't reset.

Can anyone help me with that, please?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have the YLOD (yellow light of death) it happens sometimes after a software update or some other malfunction with the system. In this case sometimes a reflow or a reball of the system might work. But as it stands it might be more worth it to just buy another system. At my repair shop we get many of these PS3's going bad either due to age or overheating. I'd recommend trying to first popping out your hard drive to see if you can even get it to boot up to the recovery menu. If that doesn't work, a reflow or a motherboard replacement are possible solutions.